# How to concatenate two registers?

Tags: register, string-manipulation

Is there some built in functionality in Vim to merge the contents of two registers into a single register by appending the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you would like to happen when e.g. one register contains a linewise selection and the other one contains a block selection. But for the easy case, you can always do (as noted in a comment)

```
:let @c=@a.@b
```

and have the concatenation of register a and b in register c. But note, this might have funny effects, if the registers contain blockwise selections (or one register is of a different type than the other).

Comment: If *not* the registers contain blockwise selections?  I'd edit, but I don't know what you meant to say.

Comment: This is close enough to what I wanted. I forgot to mention it in my OP, but my goal is to make it so that I can copy  string after string and produce a long string consisting of all copied parts. In my case it is to yank the BibTeX keys from the bibliography file into a single LaTeX citation like so: `\cite{smith2015,knuth1999,lindhe2016}`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want to merge `"a` and `"b` into `"c`:

```
call setreg('c', getreg('a').getreg('b'))
```

You can of course replace `a`, `b` and `c` by whatever register you want.

---

For a bit more of details:

`getreg('x')` will return the content of the register `x` as a string.

In vim you can concatenate two strings with `.` like this:

```
let str1 = 'foo'
let str2 = 'bar'
let result = str1 . str2
" result is equal to 'foobar'
```

Thus `getreg('a').getreg('b')` concatenate the content of registers `"a` and `"b`.

Finally `setreg()` allows you set the content of a register.

---

See the doc for more details:

- [`:h getreg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getreg%28%29)
- [`:h setreg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setreg%28%29)

Comment: Another way to do this would be: `:let @c = @a . @b`.

Comment: @garyjohn Ahah yes that is *much* easier! Using `setreg` became an automatism for me because I often had problems with `let @...` but most of the time these problems were related to the registers types so here it is not really a good argument.

Answer (score 3):

When registers only contain strings, we can do it with the old

```
:let @c = @a . @b
```

If you want to handle the registers as lists (one element per line), then you'll need to use the new functions described by @statox, but beware, lists are concatenated with `+`, not `.`.

```
:call setreg('c', getreg('a', 1, 1) + getreg('b', 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

*Additionally and as an alternative:*
if you only want to **append** something **onto an allready filled register**,
you can use the "uppercase-version" of the register-name.

For example:

- you're marking a line of text with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>,
- you'r "yanking" that text into register @a with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>, **<kbd>a</kbd>**, <kbd>y</kbd>
- next you're marking another line of text ...
- and this one, you're appending onto register @a with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>, **<kbd>A</kbd>**, <kbd>y</kbd>

As result you have two lines of text in register @a.